# How to split a string by commas and bind it to a Nested Table collection in PL/SQL Oracle

Tags: sql, string, oracle, plsql, split

I have a string like this:

```
'tiger,lion,fish,parrot'
```

And i would like to split by commas like this:

```
'tiger'
'lion'
'fish'
'parrot'
```

And then bind each one to a nested table like this:

```
TYPE my_nested_table IS TABLE OF VARCHAR (80);

my_table my_nested_table := my_nested_table ('tiger','lion','fish','parrot');
```

How can i do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Option 1:

You can create a PL/SQL function to split the string:

```sql
DECLARE
  TYPE my_nested_table IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(80);

  my_table my_nested_table;

  FUNCTION split_String(
    i_str    IN  VARCHAR2,
    i_delim  IN  VARCHAR2 DEFAULT ','
  ) RETURN my_nested_table DETERMINISTIC
  AS
    p_result       my_nested_table := my_nested_table();
    p_start        NUMBER(5) := 1;
    p_end          NUMBER(5);
    c_len CONSTANT NUMBER(5) := LENGTH( i_str );
    c_ld  CONSTANT NUMBER(5) := LENGTH( i_delim );
  BEGIN
    IF c_len > 0 THEN
      p_end := INSTR( i_str, i_delim, p_start );
      WHILE p_end > 0 LOOP
        p_result.EXTEND;
        p_result( p_result.COUNT ) := SUBSTR( i_str, p_start, p_end - p_start );
        p_start := p_end + c_ld;
        p_end := INSTR( i_str, i_delim, p_start );
      END LOOP;
      IF p_start <= c_len + 1 THEN
        p_result.EXTEND;
        p_result( p_result.COUNT ) := SUBSTR( i_str, p_start, c_len - p_start + 1 );
      END IF;
    END IF;
    RETURN p_result;
  END;
BEGIN
  my_table := split_string( 'tiger,lion,fish,parrot' );
  
  FOR i IN 1 .. my_table.COUNT LOOP
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( my_table(i) );
  END LOOP;
END;
/
```

## Option 2:

You can split the string using a recursive SQL query:

```sql
DECLARE
  TYPE my_nested_table IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(80);

  my_table my_nested_table;
  
  input VARCHAR2(4000) := 'tiger,lion,fish,parrot';
BEGIN
  WITH bounds ( value, start_pos, end_pos ) AS (
    SELECT input, 1, INSTR( input, ',', 1 ) FROM DUAL
    UNION ALL
    SELECT value, end_pos + 1, INSTR( value, ',', end_pos + 1 )
    FROM   bounds
    WHERE  end_pos > 0
  )
  SELECT CASE end_pos
         WHEN 0
         THEN SUBSTR( value, start_pos )
         ELSE SUBSTR( value, start_pos, end_pos - start_pos )
         END
  BULK COLLECT INTO my_table
  FROM   bounds;

  FOR i IN 1 .. my_table.COUNT LOOP
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( my_table(i) );
  END LOOP;
END;
/
```

## Option 3:

You can use regular expressions in a hierarchical query:

```sql
DECLARE
  TYPE my_nested_table IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(80);

  my_table my_nested_table;
  
  input VARCHAR2(4000) := 'tiger,lion,fish,parrot';
BEGIN
  SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR( input, '([^,]*)(,|$)', 1, LEVEL, NULL, 1 )
  BULK COLLECT INTO my_table
  FROM   DUAL
  CONNECT BY LEVEL < REGEXP_COUNT( input, '([^,]*)(,|$)' );

  FOR i IN 1 .. my_table.COUNT LOOP
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( my_table(i) );
  END LOOP;
END;
/
```

---

All of these populate your collection and then output:

> ```
> tiger
> lion
> fish
> parrot
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=995d7526a4f0a891138a54f756e593f7)*

Comment: Thank you! The third option is the best fit! Less code.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you really need to use that particular nested table definition, I'd suggest just using the `dbms_utility.uncl_array` type which then allows you to just call the `dbms_utility.comma_to_table` method to parse the string.

```
declare
  l_str      varchar2(1000) := 'tiger,lion,fish,parrot';
  l_num_tbls integer;
  my_table  DBMS_UTILITY.uncl_array;
begin
  dbms_utility.comma_to_table( list => l_str,
                               tablen => l_num_tbls,
                               tab    => my_table );
  

  for i in 1.. my_table.count
  loop
    dbms_output.put_line( my_table(i) );
  end loop;
end;
/
```

If you have a recent version of APEX installed, you can also use the `apex_string.parse` method (earlier versions with `apex_util.comma_to_table` can so something similar)

```
declare
  type table_t is table of varchar2(80);

  l_str      varchar2(1000) := 'tiger,lion,fish,parrot';
  my_table   table_t;
begin
  select *
    bulk collect into my_table
    from table( apex_string.split( l_str, ',' ) );


  for i in 1.. my_table.count
  loop
    dbms_output.put_line( my_table(i) );
  end loop;
end;
/
```

If you can use the built-in APEX table type, that can be further simplified

```
declare
  l_str      varchar2(1000) := 'tiger,lion,fish,parrot';
  my_table   apex_t_varchar2;
begin
  my_table :=  apex_string.split( l_str, ',' );    

  for i in 1.. my_table.count
  loop
    dbms_output.put_line( my_table(i) );
  end loop;
end;
/
```

Comment: As a note: [`DBMS_UTILITY.UNCL_ARRAY`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/arpls/DBMS_UTILITY.html#GUID-6429CBD7-9E58-4831-8EE4-5D2F52B72817) is a PL/SQL associative array data type, which cannot be used in SQL statements in earlier Oracle versions. [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=6b0a541782c7385bdebafb6777a3ab56)

Answer (score 0):

You can split the string using hiearchical query, loop through it and add individual values into the nested table or use bulk collect to add every values once at a time into nested table.

Query to split the string is:

```
Select regexp_substr(str_val, '[^,]+', 1, level) as indvdl_val
From dual
Connect by regexp_substr(str_val, '[^,]+', 1, level) is not null
```